# VBA For loop with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a for loop using the last row as my row count, but for some reason its not running. And the same thing if I put a number instead of LR, it works perfectly fine.

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    If (Cells(i, 8).Value <> "") Then
        Cells(i, 13).Value = (Cells(i, 12).Value - Cells(i, 11).Value)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The thing here might be that you have used implicit sheet reference > `LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is taking the last row from the implicit `ActiveSheet`. The same thing happens with `Cells` further on, so you might want to look into using a `With` statement to refer to a sheets `CodeName` and put a dot in front of your range object to make them explicit

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine, but not in the way you intended it to work. That's most likely because you have use a implicit sheet reference;

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

The line above will take the last used row from the currently active sheet, so the above line can also be read as `LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

The same will happen with things like `Cells(i, 8).Value` and `Cells(i, 13).Value = (Cells(i, 12).Value - Cells(i, 11).Value)` which will read like `ActiveSheet.Cells(i,8).Value` etc.

An explicit reference would include the sheet you want to refer to. So for example: `LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

To prevent multiple longer line refering to the same worksheet, I would recommend to use a `With` statement to make your references explicit:

```
Dim LR As Long i as long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 8).Value <> "" Then
            .Cells(i, 13).Value = .Cells(i, 12).Value - .Cells(i, 11).Value
        End If
    Next i
End with
```

If this still wouldn't make your loop run, than you'll have to check your first column to see if there is actual data beyond row 2.